# Do I have to install WSS first to use MOSS07

Tags: sharepoint-2007, wss

I just spoke with an college about SharePoint, he then mentioned that I would have to install WSS first and then install SharePoint 2007 ontop of that. Is this true?

I always understood that the whole SharePoint architecture is build upon WSS, so when installing SharePoint 2007 WSS is automatically installed because without it, it wouldn't even work!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - WSS does not need to be installed separately, the MOSS installation will do it for you.

Comment: Is it some manner a (microsoft) best practice to install wss first and then ontop of that MOSS07?

Comment: As @MattB mentions, The MOSS installer does WSS for you as part of the install.

Comment: @elhombre: agree with @Dave - installing WSS before MOSS is not best practice and not needed. The one caveat is that service packs (and many patches/security fixes) will require you to install both a WSS and a MOSS version - it is always noted in the MOSS documentation when that is required.